# Can I still use the YouTube autoplaylists from a channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

It used to be that if you clicked a video to play from a channel's Videos dropdown, it would automatically stick you in a playlist titled "More From User" that would autoplay the next video when your current one ended. I found it extremely helpful. It seems this doesn't happen automatically for me any more.

Was this feature removed or is there some way I can turn this back on and use that playlist for any given channel again?

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood you rigt you want to view a playlist of the users uploaded videos? well this is done by going to the "start page" of the channel. Scroll down a little and look to the right for "*Featured Playlists*" There should be a playlist there named "*Uploaded videos*" click there.
Otherwise if the channels settings is so that it displays playlists in the channel and none of the playlist controls are shown you can look in the URL of the page. If it looks something like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/UKFDubstep/#playlists/PL71B8152559FA2805
```

take the long code at the end or wherever it is located in the URL and paste it to the end of this address:

```
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=
```

So that is becomes something like http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL71B8152559FA2805

Comment: Ohh, yeah that might work, I'll try this when I can. Wonder why they ditched the automatic playlist...